# Advanced Heading numbering and formatting in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

I am attempting to use heading styles and multilevel lists/numbering to format the headings and subheadings of my masters thesis.

The style I am trying to achieve looks like this:

Chapter 1

1.1 Heading 2

1.1.1 Heading 3

1.1.1.1 Heading 4

This has been surprisingly difficult to achieve. I know it is possible to define new multilevel lists but I'm having trouble getting level 2 to continue the numbering after level 1 if I set the numbering style to none.

I know this has been done but I've not been able to find a walkthrough of how to do it.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into the question, just click the "Post Your Answer" button instead (you are allowed/encouraged to answer your own questions).  So edit out your solution and post it as an answer, or this question may be closed as 'not a real question'.

Comment: I've edited the answer out of the question and into an answer for you.  Please copy the answer text into your own answer and select it as the best answer (green check mark). Then you'll receive any points for future upvotes. Then this answer will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution was determined by OP, this answer should be deleted once the OP has copied into their own answer.**

SOLUTION:

This was embarrassingly easy but here is how to do that. The problem was in the fact that I was trying to remove numbering of the chapters and manually say Chapter X , when clearly it was better to let Word number the chapter.

The way I did it was to start with the basic 1 Heading 1 1.1 Heading 2 ... multi-level list style where it would say:

1 Introduction

1.1 bla

1.1.1 bla2

2 Background

2.1 bla

Then I went to "define a new multi-level list" at the bottom of the expanded multilevel list dropdown. This allows you to start with the already-close mml style. Select level 1 on the left to modify and in the "Enter formatting for number" section, just insert the text "Chapter" before the variable number (depending on which level of your chapters you had selected at the time it might show a 1 or a 2 but those are the variable numbers generated by the system). After that all you should have to do is highlight the text of a new chapter heading and set to heading 1 and it will say Chapter X Title. You can add any other formatting like Chapter X: or whatever. I think there are other ways to do this but this works for me.